# Read only the first 5 characters and discard rest

Tags: java, io

I want to read the only first 5 characters from `System.in` and discard rest to the `EOL` character if the stream contains more than that (In order to start reading next line). Here's what I tried:

```
private static final int READ_COUNT = 5; 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int readCharacters = 0;
    int character;
    do{
        character = reader.read();
        doJob();
        if(++readCharacters >= READ_COUNT){
            discardRest(reader);
            break;
        }
    } while(character != '\n');

    System.out.println((char) reader.read());
}

private static void discardRest(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    while(true){
        int character = reader.read();
        if(character == '\n')
            break;
    } 
}

public static void doJob() throws InterruptedException{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

It works, but it's pain. And it looks ugly as hell. I am not quite sure if it's reliable. Is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: @eldo In this case to emulate some job.

Comment: Why don't you simply read a line from the buffered reader, and then just use the first five characters of that line?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Because reading the whole line may cause OutOfMemoryError. Depending on the line....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have simply made a class of my own:

```
public class SkipLineBufferedReader extends BufferedReader
{

    public SkipLineBufferedReader(Reader in) 
    {
        super(in);
    }

    public SkipLineBufferedReader(Reader in, int sz) 
    {
        super(in, sz);
    }

    //Return \n or -1 if EOF
    public int skipLine() throws IOException
    {
        int ch;
        do
        {
            ch = read();
        }
        while (ch != -1 && ch != '\n');

        return ch;
    }
}
```

That simply contains the logic to skip to the next line reading one char at a time.
Beware that in `discardRest` if you reach the *EOF* before any *EOL* you'll loop forever.

The use of the class above is intuitive:

```
private static final int READ_COUNT = 5; 

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    SkipLineBufferedReader li 
        = new SkipLineBufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int readCharacters = 0;
    int character;

    do
    {
        character = li.read();

        System.out.println("JOB WITH " + character);

        if(++readCharacters >= READ_COUNT)
        {
            li.skipLine();

            break;
        }
    } while(character != '\n');

    System.out.println((char) li.read());
}
```

I don't know if you need more specific methods, like one that convert the first characters into a string, but `BufferedReader` has `read(char[] cbuf)` and `read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` which are very handy to deal with strings.

Beware of dealing with string when reading user files, you cannot assume there are always at least five characters, a blind `substring` will throws.

Comment: Thanks, I love this solution. But actually, I read to the end of line or when I reach go beyond the limit.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
String fiveChars=reader.nextLine().substring(0, 5);
```

and repeat the last line every time you need next 5 characters.

Comment: Are you sure that if the line is very very large we don't run OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: obiviously you can use BufferedReader and such

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to write THAT long lines

Comment: Hm... Don't see how it solves the problem. We load the entire line in memory anyway

Comment: Well, maybe they won't. But the fact that they can is not good.

Comment: Well, I've been programing for a while and had 1M byte[] and never got said error, so I doubt anyone has the patience